# Python - Selenium: Why move_by_offset Doesn't Work. Solution Please

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make an element click using the x,y coordinates.
So I decided to use the `move_by_offset` to make click on the element. But for me, it doesn't Work

Why `move_by_offset` and `click()` the element doesn't work?
Please help.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

chromedriver = "path...."
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

zero_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//input[@class="RNmpXc"])[2]')
x_body_offset = zero_elem.location["x"]
y_body_offset = zero_elem.location["y"]
print("Body coordinates: {}, {}".format(x_body_offset, y_body_offset))

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(6)
# zero_elem.click()
action.move_by_offset( x_body_offset, y_body_offset ).click().perform()
print('22')
```

Comment: Message Error:  "Instance of 'ActionChains' has no 'build' member",

Comment: I trying now to change to another elemento, to view how it works, and now with these one works,                                                                                                                                                 code:     THE SAME BUT CHANGE -> ```zero_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@class="NKcBbd"]')```